# FormData contains TWO view states when making AJAX post?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page where I am submitting an image to be uploaded. For some reason, the FormData that I am passing along contains TWO view state variables? Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

[image]

```
 function mainUploadImages() {
            $("#mainUploadFileShowWorking").show();
            var showWorkingMessage = "<div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<div class='media'>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<div class='spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm text-success mt-1 mr-2' role='status'>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span>";
            showWorkingMessage += "</div>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<div class='media-body'><strong>Saving</strong> Please wait for a little while...</div>";
            showWorkingMessage += "</div>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<div class='progress mt-1' style='height:3px;'>";
            showWorkingMessage += "<div id='mainImageShowProgressBar' class='progress-bar bg-success' style='width: 0%;'></div>";
            showWorkingMessage += "</div></div>";

            $("#btnMainUploadImage").prop("disabled", true);
            $('#mainUploadFileShowWorking').html(showWorkingMessage);

            var isProfileImage = $('#imageIsProfile').is(':checked') ? "1" : "0";

            var formData = new FormData($('#aspnetForm').get(0));

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/property_details/main_image_upload.aspx?pi=' + isProfileImage,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) {
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', mainImageProgressHandlingFunction, false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                success: function (ret) {
                    $('#mainUploadFileShowWorking').fadeOut();
                    $('#mainImageFileUploader').val('');
                    $('#mainImageFileUploaderLabel').html('Choose file');
                    isLoading(0);
                    new Noty({
                        text: '<h5>Images uploaded</h5>The images have been uploaded.', type: 'success', timeout: 2000
                    }).show();
                    $("#btnMainUploadImage").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#imageIsProfile").prop("checked", false);
                    loadProfileImage();
                    loadPropertyImages();
                },
                error: function (ret) {
                    console.log(ret);
                    isLoading(0);
                    $('#mainUploadFileShowWorking').fadeOut();
                    $('#mainImageFileUploader').val('');
                    $('#mainImageFileUploaderLabel').html('Choose file');
                    $("#btnMainUploadImage").prop("disabled", false);
                    new Noty({ text: '<h5>Error</h5>An unspecified error occurred, please try again', type: 'error', timeout: 2000 }).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the modal that handles the file selection:

```
 <div class="modal fade modal-content-right" id="propertyUploadImage" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
                    Upload property image
                    <div class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm text-warning customAjaxLoader mt-1" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-form">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Image File</label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                        <input id="mainImageFileUploader" name="mainImageFileUploader" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
                                        <label id="mainImageFileUploaderLabel" class="custom-file-label" for="mainImageFileUploader">Choose file</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="imageIsProfile">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="imageIsProfile">Set image as profile image</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-3" id="mainUploadFileShowWorking"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer shadow-none">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnMainUploadImage" type="button" onclick="mainUploadImages();">Upload</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd also like to mention that I simply copy & pasted this code (with small adjustments), and there the code works fine??

This page throws a "corrupt view state" error, which is probably due to the double view states being passed along. The viewstate in position 0 in the screenshot is correct.

Comment: Why would you care if the page has 1 or 5 viewstates? You can't mess with them, so you don't care anyway. If you have a master page/child page setup, then yes, your find and see 2 viewstates. Quite sure if if you drop in some update panels, then each of those also has their own viewstate. So no care or worry here. Fact of having 2 view states is unlikely your issue. However, it not clear why you using a custom post-back, and you would be better to use a .ajax method, and pass the value(s) in question to the server, and thus not have a post back with view state. So, use a standard ajax call